# UI Glitches in windows mobile 10 App

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-10-universal

I'm developing new application on Windows 10 (UWP) but I'm suffering UI Glitches in the resources (icons & images) when the application loading.

there any solution to solve this problem??

For Example :when I added the background Image for the root Grid in the XAML Page its loading with large delay when app run, it causes Glitches for page the however the image size is small .

Comment: Could you share [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can reproduce your issue? Besides, if you are developing a Windows 10 Mobile app, please remove the [tag:windows-phone-8.1] tag.

Answer (score 0):

We'll I'm not sure what you mean by UI Glitches, but have a look at resource dictionaries...

ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I mean when I added the background Image for the root Grid in the XAML Page loading with large delay when app run, however the image size is small. Devian